# Expanding on a previous question about airline routing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039403/writing-an-airline-routing-algorithm-efficiently) is the question I was referring to. The answer given there works if the number of stops in the route is not specified by the user, but how would this solution change if the number of stops/connections were to be explicitly specified by the user? So it wouldn't be as much of an optimal route problem (though it still is) it would be more along the lines of finding a route with EXACTLY N stops(nodes) in it while still being somewhat optimal.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is unfortunately known to be NP-hard by a reduction from the [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).  This means that if you really do want to be able to solve the problem of finding the shortest path that makes exactly N stops (assuming, of course, you don't want any cycles) then you probably shouldn't expect to get an algorithm that's polynomial in N.

Comment: Sure, it's exponential in N, which is O(1) if N has an upper bound. No?

Comment: @Mike Dunvaley- Yes, but you have to keep a few things in mind.  First, O(1) doesn't mean "fast"; if your N is large, you might end up with such a huge constant that the runtime of the algorithm would be impractically large.  Second, the fact that the algorithm is exponential in N doesn't mean the algorithm is O(1) for fixed N; for example, if the algorithm is O(k^N), where k is the size of the graph, the algorithm might be prohibitively expensive for N > 3.

Comment: I agree. I was just thinking, for the airline routing problem, more than 3 links are really rare, I suspect, so being non-polynomial is kind of academic.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey- Oh, absolutely. :-)  I just wanted to give the OP a warning that trying to solve this problem in general is going to be difficult and in the special case for even reasonable N (say, N = 4) is also unlikely to be very tractable.  There may be a good solution for N = 2 or N = 3, though I suspect it's going to be O(n^2) or O(n^3) in those cases.

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm glad you enjoy teaching. I was a teacher, and I sometimes have a beef with how CS is taught, but really it's a noble, difficult, and satisfying job.